# I'd like some help in a basic game idea in C. [beginner]

Tags: c, console

So hello,

I am trying to get some experience on C, im at bigginer level.

I need so help if you will..

1) id like to make a console based game, so I have a char 2d array and i want first of all my game to have some kind of border.. mean: 1st n' last row, 1st n'last line, I want to put some asterisks so I can make a simple border.

Here is what I've tried:

```
  //include etc
    //main..
    //int i,j
   char myarray[22][76]={{' '}};
   for(i=0;i>22;i++){
      for(j=0;j<76;j++){
        if(i==0 || i==22)
          myarray[i][j]='*';
        else if(j==0 && i>0 || j==75 && i>0)
          myarray[i][j]='*';
        else
        myarray[i][j]='';
    }
     printf("%d",myarray[i][j]);
     printf("\n");
   }
```

-I think that i must erase i>0 in the conditions since the program wont enter else if untill i>0, cause of the if condition.
-it might be completelly wrong but thats what i thought.

2)
since I will have a player and treasures and traps, I want everytime my player moves the whole screen to be redrawn. But I dont want to be redrawn from the start i want it to be redrawn so it can show the current state of the game. ex. if the player has found a treasure then the screen must be drawn without the treasure on it and with the player at his current position.

Do I need the (border,traps,treasures,player) in same function? and how I can achieve the redraw of the screen in each move?

I run windows 10 and codeblocks+netbeans doesn't work at 10, I dont know why and I cant fix it atm , I tried online complier but they have limitation of code lines and excecution.

Comment: Why do you need codeblocks and netbeans? There's a free edition of Visual Studio.

Comment: downloading VS 2015 UPDATE 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//include etc
//main..
//int i,j

char myarray[22][76] = { { ' ' } };
for (i = 0; i<22; i++){
    for (j = 0; j<76; j++){
        if (i == 0 || i == 21)
            myarray[i][j] = '*';
        else if (j == 0 || j == 75)
            myarray[i][j] = '*';
        printf("%c", myarray[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: oh i accidentally puted > instead of <. thanks , its exactly how i thought